# 1C Склад как лучше организовать заполнение таблиц?

Tags: sql, postgresql, 1с

Пишу интерфейс склада есть таблицы:

```
    CREATE TABLE "sklad"
(
  "Name" character varying NOT NULL,
  "Uint" character varying NOT NULL,
  "Count" numeric,
  "Changed" boolean,
  "OneCID" character varying,
  UNIQUE ("Name")
)
```

В моей архитектуре есть возможность добавления новых складов в организацию, на данный момент реализовано так: Что при регистрации склада создается новая таблица с новым именем склада. Представим что на 1 складе более 10 000 позиций и количество складов около 2000. Возникает вопрос как лучше организовать заполнение? 1 Склад = 1 таблица. Или 1 Таблица с товарами и в строках указывается наименование склада.

```
 CREATE TABLE "sklad"
    (
      "NameSklad" varchar NOT NULL,
      "Name" character varying NOT NULL,
      "Uint" character varying NOT NULL,
      "Count" numeric,
      "Changed" boolean,
      "OneCID" character varying,
      UNIQUE ("Name")
    )
```

Как это реализовано в 1С? И как сделать правильно?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не показана практическая ценность вопроса. См. [бесполезное знание](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4410/)

Comment: Оно не бесполезное, мне надо знать как реализовано данное действие в 1С.

Comment: Ну об этом вы не написали "надо знать" -> "для того, чтобы..." -- возможно, что с этим пояснением задача и приобретёт практический смысл. Я же и выразился корректно: "ценность не показана", а не "не несёт никакой ценности".

Comment: Добавил более информативное описание.

Comment: Ну, я бы более явно написал слово "производительность", но допустим. Данный вопрос уже не нужно закрывать потому что можно считать, что есть практическая ценность вопроса. Но его всё равно нужно закрыть, т.к. нет никакой конкретики. Приведите запросы, планы запросов. Пока сразу три причины закрытия подходят для вашего вопроса. Я не придираюсь, но телепатов нет, пока что у вас вопрос весьма расплывчат - и на него даже пытаться отвечать никому не хочется.

Comment: Все, на более, меня уже не хватит, куда еще более подробно...

Comment: А что вам мешает получить список таблиц в базе, создать склад, получить новый список таблиц и сравнить результаты? Для чего вам вообще знать, как это сделано в 1С, вы убеждены, что они всё сделали правильно? Зря, если так :)

Comment: У меня есть список таблиц в отдельной таблице =) Там поля ID, NameSklad, Alias, CreateDate =) Вот у меня и возник вопрос как будет сделать лучше? А про 1С - эту программу  все используют и на это можно сослаться в случае чего =)

Comment: Это я вам рассказал способ выяснить, делает ли 1С по отдельной таблице на склад. А ссылаться на них, конечно, можно, но это нисколько не технический довод. В IT вообще не бывает "правильно", существует лишь конкретная разница между двумя известными вещами :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В 1с данные по всем складам хранятся в одном регистре. Регистр это две таблицы в одной хранятся обороты ( движения товаров) в другой остатки на конец каждого месяца от начала ведения учета. 
В postges структура 1с работает плохо на большом объеме данных. 
В целом как правильно вопрос философский и ответа не имеет. 
Специально для Dside. Лично мне вопрос понятен, практический смысл имеет,  хотя признаю задача очень специфическая.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать запрос через СКД. Там и настроить - хоть искать по складам, хоть по товарам и т.д..

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]